# Multiple definitions of a property not allowed in strict mode

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, vue.js, laravel-elixir

I'm using the following in my VueJS/ Laravel project with

```
"laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-14",
    "laravel-elixir-browsersync-official": "^1.0.0",
    "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.2.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",

"bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
```

In trying to run my project everything works in all browser except IE which throws

> SCRIPT1046: Multiple definitions of a property not allowed in strict mode

The code in question seems to be coming from Twitter bootstrap 3.3.7 near the following

```
val("/*!\n * Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com)\n * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.\n * Licensed under the MIT license\n */\n\nif (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {\n  throw new Error('Bootstrap\\'s JavaScript requires jQuery')\n}\n\n+function ($) {\n  'use strict';\n  var version = $.fn.jquery.split(' ')[0].split('.')\n  if ((version[0] < 2 && version[1] < 9) || (version[0] == 1 && version[1] == 9 && version[2] < 1) || (version[0] > 3)) {\n    throw new Error('Bootstrap\\'s JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 4')\n  }\n}(jQuery);\n\n/* ========================================================================\n * Bootstrap: transition.js v3.3.7\n * http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#transitions\n * ========================================================================\n * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.\n * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)\n * ======================================================================== */\n\n\n+function ($) {\n  'use strict';\n\n  // CSS TRANSITION SUPPORT (Shoutout: http://www.modernizr.com/)\n  // ============================================================\n\n  function transitionEnd() {\n    var el = document.createElement('bootstrap')\n\n    var transEndEventNames = {\n      WebkitTransition : 'webkitTransitionEnd',\n      MozTransition    : 'transitionend',\n      OTransition      : 'oTransitionEnd otransitionend',\n      transition       : 'transitionend'\n    }\n\n    for (var name in transEndEventNames) {\n      if (el.style[name] !== undefined) {\n        return { end: transEndEventNames[name] }\n      }\n    }\n\n    return false // explicit for ie8 (  ._.)\n  }\n\n  // http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/css-transitions\n  $.fn.emulateTransitionEnd = function (duration) {\n    var called = false\n    var $el = this\n    $(this).one('bsTransitionEnd', function () { called = true })\n    var callback = function () { if (!called) $($el).trigger($.support.transition.end) }\n    setTimeout(callback, duration)\n    return this\n  }\n\n  $(function () {\n
```

I'm not sure what this means as I've  NEVER encountered such a problem. What could this be?

P.S. can't set up a fiddle as it's running dynamically

Comment: Are you using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) (`"use strict"`)? This error happens when you are running in strict mode, and give a property multiple definitions. Example: `obj = { prop: 1, prop: 2};`. More here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br230269(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: Maybe remove bootstrap from your dependencies and import its source code version in the page to locate the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Well I had to disable "use strict" by adding babel blacklist properties to my package.json file.

```
{
  babel: {
       blacklist: ['useStrict']
}
}
```